# XmlMapper with same @XmlElement but different @XmlElementWrapper

Tags: java, jackson-dataformat-xml

I hava a class which has some String-Lists that I want to marshal via Jackson. And for better usage I want to have in eacht list the same Element-Name. So I annotate like this:

```
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElementWrapper;

public class MyClass
{
    public String title;

    @XmlElementWrapper(name="hints")
    @XmlElement(name="text")
    public List<String> hints;

    @XmlElementWrapper(name="warnings")
    @XmlElement(name="text")
    public List<String> warnings;

    @XmlElementWrapper(name="errors")
    @XmlElement(name="text")
    public List<String> errors;
}
```

But at runtime I get an exception *Could not write JSON: Multiple fields representing property "text"*. I've also tried this with no effect:

```
// mapper instanceof com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper
mapper.configure(MapperFeature.USE_WRAPPER_NAME_AS_PROPERTY_NAME, true);
```

What do I need in addition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a perfect solution, but still a good workaround when I seperate the list itself in a new class and remove wrapping (for it is wrapped by the members using this new type):

```
public class StringList
{
    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
    @XmlElement(name="text")
    public final List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    public void add( String msg )
    {
        list.add( msg );
    }
}
```

... so my class will look like:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public String title;

    public StringList hints;

    public StringList warnings;

    public StringList errors;
}
```